# Change Background Image

Tags: css, joomla, joomla1.7

I have a website developed in Joomla 1.7. I want to keep background Image only at home page not on other pages.

code is like this.

**HTML**

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  all content goes here
 </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{margin:0px; padding:0px;}

#wrapper{background:url(../images/bg-img.jpg) repeat-x;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Purmou mentioned, none of these methods will work because Joomla uses the same index.php from the template so every page on the site will include the CSS class or ID if you code it in there.

Lucky for you, Joomla took this in to account and you can easily do what you are trying to do with a simple mod to your template. Joomla uses what is called the page class suffix to allow you to make page specific CSS. Any time you create a menu item, you have an option to include a page class suffix which will only be added to pages within that menu item. In order to put that suffix in the body tag so you can achieve what you are trying to do, add this code to your index.php in your template:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$params =  & $app->getParams('com_content');
$pageclass = trim($params->get('pageclass_sfx'));
?>
<body id="<?php echo $pageclass ? $pageclass : 'default'; ?>">
```

If you add a page class suffix to a menu item, it will be inserted as the body tag ID. If you don't it will use "default" instead. This way you can control the ID of the body on a per page basis and male changes specific to every page on the site.

Comment: Thanks Brent, This is what I want because this is truly smart answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give `ID` in your `body` then define `css` for that page.

Like This:

**HTML:**

```
<body id="home">
 <div id="wrapper">
  all content goes here
 </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#home #wrapper{background:url(../images/bg-img.jpg) repeat-x;}
#wrapper{background:red}
```

Comment: but this css will remain same at every page, means background image will remain on every page. can you please explain it

Comment: the background-image is only in #home page #wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Make a second wrapper (only on your homepage), which has an id of "homepage_wrapper", and use CSS to set a background for that.

Comment: how to set second wrapper only on homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use class as well on it.

```
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper" class="home">
 all content goes here
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
 #wrapper{}
 .home {background:url(../images/bg-img.jpg) repeat-x;}
```

If you will use background on (#wrapper) that will overwrite the .home class property so please make sure you will use the background in (.home) class

Comment: I am using joomla means css will remain same at every page, means background image will remain on every page. can you please explain your idea to change background image .

Comment: you can put this class in home page only. <style>.home {background:url(../images/bg-img.jpg) repeat-x;}
  </style> do not put this class in external file

Comment: I can not put that class in home page only because the wrapper is not the part of main container, I want background image fit to resolution and main container is only of 960px width. So how can I use the Outer wrapper in Main container. Hope you understand.

Comment: Set the background for only the required page, remove the background css from the main css file which is being used everywhere.

Comment: As per you code if I set `.home` class to required page and apply background image to that. But if my page has width of 960px then how does my background image will fit to the the resolution.

Comment: If Its fixed with layout so no need to worried about resolution.

Comment: Joomla uses a template file, so every page will have the `.home` class applied to it anyways.